# Computing the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1533157})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to compute the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1533157})$ in Magma. Can anyone explain why it's taking so long to compute? I'm currently running Magma V2.18-7. Below is my code:

```
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH"); 
K := QuadraticField(1533157);
ClassNumber(K);
```

Comment: I just tried it in Sage and got 4 pretty quickly (less than 5 seconds). Check your code again. I used 

K=QuadraticField(1533157,'x')

K.class_number()

Comment: Have you tried some forum/mailing list specialized for Magma? It might be some intricate internal optimization, or whatever.

Comment: @BrentJ: My code seems to work fine when I replace 1533157 with something else.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Do you know where I can find such a mailing list/forum?

Comment: I am running Magma 2.19-4 in my laptop, and "K := QuadraticField(1533157); ClassNumber(K);" returned 4 immediately.

Comment: If I add the first command "SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");" the calculation is still immediate, and the result is 4.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it's an issue with V2.18-7. The Magma online calculator also running 2.19-4 seems to compute it fine.

Comment: No, I don't know where to find such forum. I also don't know where to find a dating site aimed for math students; but that doesn't make it right to post here requests for dates.

Comment: Just in case you don't have Magma or Sage at hand, you can always use wolfram-alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NumberFieldClassNumber%5BSqrt%5B1533157%5D%5D It only takes a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

EEDDIITTT: I KNOW the final answer is four!!!!!! My viewpoint gives eight and then identifies pairs, resulting in four. See quote from blog at the end!!!

When this first came up I had not written the class number program yet: the class group of indefinite binary quadratic forms has eight elements, for the number field you just identify $(a,b,c)$ with $(-a,b,-c)$ and **get down to four elements**. I discuss the explicit mapping from forms (triples) to ideal thingies in a few places in http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/

```
 1533157    factored   23 * 191 *  349

    1.             1        1237        -747   cycle length            68
    2.            -1        1237         747   cycle length            68
    3.             3        1237        -249   cycle length            70
    4.            -3        1237         249   cycle length            70
    5.            71        1221        -149   cycle length            78
    6.           -71        1221         149   cycle length            78
    7.           149        1221         -71   cycle length            78
    8.          -149        1221          71   cycle length            78

  form class number is   8

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

EEEEEDDDIIIIITTTTTTT: Quoting from my BBBBBBLLLLLLOOOOOOOGGGG:

So, the mapping to ideals says  IDENTIFY $ \langle A,B,-C \rangle  $ and
$ \langle -A,B,C \rangle  ,$ send them to the same ideal. Why not? We already have an equality of ideals in 
$$ \left[ A, \frac{B + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right]  =  \left[ -A, \frac{B + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right]. $$

The four ideals are
$$ \left[ 1, \frac{1237 + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right] , \; \;  \left[ 3, \frac{1237 + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right] , \; \; \left[ 71, \frac{1221 + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right] , \; \; \left[ 149, \frac{1221 + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right] ,    $$
where $\Delta = 1533157.$

Comment: (The first comment to the question says that Sage gets 4 here!)

Comment: Oh, that was certainly not what I meant! I was just remarking that there was seemingly different result also on the page, hoping that you'd explain where the difference comes from.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, typed in the  four winners.